# How to perform mongodb aggregations on multilevel/nested documents?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have `mongodb` collection called **tasks**. Here `T1.1` is sub task of `T1` and `T1.1.1` is sub task of `T1.1` and so on.. Subtask levels can grow more. I am using `mongodb` version `4.0`. Below is the collection data

```
---------------------------------------
task     | parent_task_id | progress(%)
---------------------------------------
T1       | null           | 20
---------------------------------------
T2       | null           | 30
---------------------------------------
T1.1     | T1             | 10
---------------------------------------
T1.2     | T1             | 10
---------------------------------------
T1.1.1   | T1.1           | 10
---------------------------------------
T1.1.2   | T1.1           | 10
---------------------------------------
T1.1.1.1 | T1.1.1         | 10
---------------------------------------
```

How do I calculate average progress of task `T1` including all subtasks(`T1.1,T1.2,T1.1.1,T1.1.2,T1.1.1.1`) using `mongodb` aggregations?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "task": {//Find all subtasks using pattern
        $regex: "^T1.*"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      "_id": null,
      "avg": {//Avg of the matched tasks' progress
        "$avg": "$progress"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Sample playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/0rPn3o7dFMz)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This solution is working fine. But if the Task id is mongodb generated id, then how do i achieve this ? @Gibbs

Comment: How do you identify if it is T1 or T2 with mongo generated id? You can have another field to identify.

Comment: Thank you @gibbs. I will generate one format , so that i can identify it is related to T1 task or T2 task